# Why assigning a variable to itself prompts a correction in Intellij idea

Tags: java, variables, assign

Why this prompts a correction:

```
int x = 3;
x = x;
```

You need to rewrite the above code into something like this:

```
int a = 3;
int b = a;
a = b;
```

The second code is accepted by Intellij Idea even if it is basically the same logic as the first, only more complicated.
The examples above are simplifications of real business logic code. No reason to provide here the real code, because even for the example above Intellij prompts you to correct that. It is not an error. The code compiles and runs ok. The self-assignment happens not in a constructor.
Why the first code is not ok?

If it helps I can come up with more elaborate code:

```
    int i = 0;
    int b = 10;
    do {
        for (i = i; i < b; i++){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        b=b+10;
    } while (//some condition);
    System.out.println("Final i: "+ i);
```

Let's say i need to print i from 0 to 9, then, if //some condition is true print the next i iterations from 10 to 19 etc.
What is the logic behind Intellij prompting to correct i=i part?

Comment: it's not an error message. It's just a notification that "x = x;" is a pointless line of code, which it is. the compiler won't check the values for a or b, so as far as the compiler is concerned, you may have changed the value of b (or a) after the int b = a;, but assigning a variable to itself is obviously pointless, and most often a typo.

Comment: Can you execute code containing a statement like this in IntelliJ? Should be possible though it *has no effect*, which eclipse states in a warning, too.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? *Why* do you need to do self-assignment?

Comment: *Very occasionally*, you might find self assignment of a volatile field, which has a use for memory consistency. However, such usages are *rare*.

Comment: Two things about your new example: The first is that unless you need `i` after the `for` loop, you should really define it inside the initialization clause of the `for` loop, as in `for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)`; Secondly, all three clauses of the `for` loop are *optional*. That means you could write e.g. `for (; i < b; i++)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I need the "i" later in the code. Your second suggestion is helpful, i might use it in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Because all (halfway decent) IDEs will warn about this, due to the following problem:

```java
public class A {
    private int a;

    public A (int a) {
        // problem, because nothing is actually done.
        a = a;

        // what you actually want.
        this.a = a;
    }

    ....
}
```

The field `a` is named the same as the parameter `a`, and therefore assigning `a = a` is a **self assignment**, instead of the intended assignment to the field `this.a = a`.

On a side note: This is not only a problem in constructors, just a decent example.

Comment: Fun fact: `int thing = thing = 1;` is valid Java.